# Possible ways to connect SharePoint Office 365 to External databases

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

Is there a way we can connect SharePoint Office 365 to Oracle & MySQL Databases and also is it possible for these databases to feed data to SharePoint Office 365 rather than SharePoint pulling the data from these databases.

Answer (score 2):

In order to connect the external database to SharePoint online, you can consider deploying the Business Connectivity Services (BCS). First of all, the subscription eligible for the BCS requires an Office 365 Enterprise E3 or E4 subscription.

If your Office 365 subscription meets the requirement, please be aware that Business Connectivity Services in a SharePoint Online tenancy can only access data from WCF Data Services and SQL Server Azure Connectors.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740(v=office.15).aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-external-data-HA102891586.aspx?CTT=1

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740(v=office.15).aspx

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/246088.aspx

Comment: Practically is it possible for other databases to feed data to SharePoint.