# Connect On-Premise Database to Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sql-server

I have a SQL table in SQL Server Management Studio that I want to set up as an external content type in Sharepoint Online. I've used Sharepoint Designer 2013 to create it, and the link works fine in that. But when I try to access the list in Sharepoint itself, it doesn't work and gives me the following error:

Unable to render the data. If the problem persists, contact your web server administrator.

Correlation ID:a73a189e-4015-4000-18d4-c1b6569642b7

Is there a way to set up an on-premise database as an external content type? If not, what would be the best way for me to populate a list using a SQL table?

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint 365, so I don't have access to the logs unfortunately.

Comment: This may help https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126100/possible-ways-to-connect-sharepoint-office-365-to-external-databases